# Storing Multiple Values in PHP Variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm in a spot of bother... I am executing a query that could potentially have 5 results (1, 2, 3, 4 or 5) and putting them in a PHP variable. I need to use this variable in another query immediately afterwards in a table where only 1 of these 5 values is present.

Currently, I believe the variable is only holding "5", the last result found, and is subsequently not finding any results in the second query if the present value is anything but "5".

I'm curious to know if there's a way to store all 5 of these values in the one variable and cycle through them in the second query without using an array?

My code is here:

```
//Find the User's ID and the ID of the last question answered
$sqlA = mysql_query("SELECT PKID, LastQuestionAnswered FROM User WHERE EmailAddress = '***'");
//If the operation produces an error, output an error message
if (!$sqlA) {
    die('Invalid query for SQLA: ' . mysql_error());
}
//Count the number of rows output
$sqlACount = mysql_num_rows($sqlA);
//If rows exist, define the values
if ($sqlACount > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlA)) {
        $sqlAPKID = $row["PKID"];
        $sqlALastQuestionAnswered = $row["LastQuestionAnswered"];
    }
}

//Find the answer given by the user to the last answered question
$sqlB = mysql_query("SELECT Answer FROM Responses WHERE User = $sqlAPKID");
//If the operation produces an error, output an error message
if (!$sqlB) {
    die('Invalid query for SQLB: ' . mysql_error());
}
//Count the number of rows output
$sqlBCount = mysql_num_rows($sqlB);
//If rows exist, define the values
if ($sqlBCount > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlB)) {
        $sqlBAnswer = $row["Answer"];
    }
}

//Find the number of the next question to be answered based on the user's previous answer and the question they answered
$sqlC = mysql_query("SELECT NextQuestion FROM Answers WHERE QuestionNumber = $sqlALastQuestionAnswered AND PKID = $sqlBAnswer");
//If the operation produces an error, output an error message
if (!$sqlC) {
    die('Invalid query for SQLC: ' . mysql_error());
}
//Count the number of rows output
$sqlCCount = mysql_num_rows($sqlC);
//If rows exist, define the values
if ($sqlCCount > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlC)) {
        $sqlCNextQuestion = $row["NextQuestion"];
    }
}
//If there is no value for $sqlCNextQuestion, the user has finished the survey
if (empty($sqlCNextQuestion)) {
    //Redirect the user to the "Survey Complete" page
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=surveycomplete.php">';
    //If there is a value for $sqlCNextQuestion, the user has not finished the survey
} else {
```

etc.

So, at present, if no value is found for `$SQLCNextQuestion`, the user is being redirected to the "Survey Complete" page.

Any ideas and help would be greatly appreciated, and be rest assured that the code will be edited to utilise PDO before rollout... :)

Comment: Have you tried using an array variable for storing multiple results ?

Comment: I'll be completely honest Pavan, I'm new to this and tried and failed! I'll do some reading and see what I come up with :)

Comment: _...cycle through them in the second query without using an array?_ Please explain as why you don't want to use an array?

Comment: Zulu better use arrays and foreach...this wil solve your purpose...

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll go and have a go and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an array (and I don't know why you wouldn't), you could concatenate the results in a single string with a delimiter (a delimiter that definitely won't be present in any potential query result), and then explode() that string later on.

That still makes it an array however, but the alternative would be to search your concatenated string by making substrings out of it, all of which is entirely messy. Please use an array :)

Comment: Thanks monkeymatrix - I'm new to this and tried an array at first and failed miserably! I'll have a read and try again. Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't know how large your array might be, consider using `array_push()` to increase the array size by 1, while adding a value. That's very useful if you don't know what array key you want to use when statically assigning an array variable, or you might add to an array infrequently.

Answer (score 0):

If You have results more than 1 just use arrays.

```
$sqlCNextQuestion[] = ...
```

instead of

```
$sqlCNextQuestion = ...
```

At end You can view results by print_r or var_dump functions

```
print_r($sqlCNextQuestion);
```

Same for $sqlBAnswer etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use implode function for example

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="A" />
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="B" />
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="C" />
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="D" />
</form>

<?php
echo implode('', $_POST['foo']);
?>
```

The attribute name in each submit button: name="foo[]" Then, in php, $_POST['foo'] contains an array with the value of each "foo[]"

```
echo implode('', $_POST['foo']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm not actually posting anything at this stage!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for best output.

```
//Count the number of rows output
$sqlALastQuestionAnswered = array();

$sqlACount = mysql_num_rows($sqlA);
$count = 0;
//If rows exist, define the values
if ($sqlACount > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlA)) {
        $sqlAPKID[$count] = $row["PKID"];
        $sqlALastQuestionAnswered[$count] = $row["LastQuestionAnswered"];
        $count++;
    }
}
```

> Count variable will contain the total number of result.
>
> Now you would be able to access particular element by array index like
>   **$sqlALastQuestionAnswered[0]** will return first value and so on.

Comment: Thanks Hardik, that's very helpful. I have a question though...I've done as you said (except around the $sqlB code), but now can't seem to initiate a foreach loop around the $sqlC code. In other words, it doesn't seem to be finding those array values to run them through my next query. Any suggestions? :)